# IOS sythesize - when to declare an internal variable?

Tags: ios, properties

I'm following along with Apple's "Hello" tutorial on iOS, and I'd like to know why it's necessary to declare the "userName" variable (to be accessed in code later). Isn't it generated by the synthesize statement?

```
@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *userName;
}

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *testField;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userName;
```

And here's the implementation of synthesize:

```
@synthesize label=_label;
@synthesize testField=_testField;
@synthesize userName=_userName;
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't always generated by the property/synthesize. That's a relatively new addition to Objective-C. The tutorial was probably written before this was the case.

Comment: Nope - it's brand new. It uses XCode 4.2, storyboards, drag and drop code generation, etc.